# GeoServer WFS set minScale

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I am new in working with GeoServer. At the beginning I tried to publish a WFS service. This works great, but this service consists of huge data. That's why I want it to start displaying the polygons at a scale of 1:2500. Is there a way to set this option in GeoServer?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please remember to specify the *exact* software in use and include details of what you have tried in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WFS is for serving vectors and has no concept of scale. Your client may provide a way to restrict requests for that data based on the scale that it is using currently.

A WMS layer can be set to have a Min and Max scale to render at in the SLD (style) file associated with the layer, which may be more suitable for your use case.